# Are opinion based questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

For instance if I ask questions concerning how good is a training program compared to others etc...

Is it allowed?

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be allowed if you asked it like that, as it's just pure opinion.

What *would* be allowed, and I'd certainly encourage it, would be if you asked what training programs are most effective *towards a particular goal* that you have.

Something like this is certainly answerable in my book:

> Is StrongLifts better than German Volume Training if I'm primarily interested  in getting a body builder's physique?

There are opinions involved to some extent, but there are fairly concrete results from different programs targeted towards specific results.